# c++, termios, non canonical, blocking, detect end of message

Tags: c++, blocking, termios

I wrote a blocking loop to read unsolicited messages. I can't have an end char to detect the end of the message, but I am pretty happy with the timeout. `VMIN=1` `VTIME=5`

Here when the recieved bytes are fewer than the buffer size, I presume the end of the messagge.

This code works, but will fail if the message is exactly 33 chars long. Any idea?

```
int l = 0;
string o = "";
char buf[33];

while(1) {
    if (l && l < 33) {
        // Messagge end, do something
    }
    l = read(fd, buf, 33);
    o.append(buf, 0, l);
}
```

Comment: right, I explained better. No it cant be <= because thats the case of a piece of the stream.

Comment: I think you actually need to create a [mcve] so it becomes clear what you want. Are all messages supposed to be multiples of exactly 33 `char`s (33, 66, 99, ...)? Do you ever clear `o` etc?

Answer (score 0):

`VMIN` should be set to `0`. If `VMIN > 0` the timer is not started until the first character arrives and the call can block indefinitely if the line is idle.

You also don't add your last `buf` to the `string` before you "do something". This should work better:

```
ssize_t l = 0; // use this type with read()
char buf[33];
std::string o;

while(true) {
    // VMIN == 0, VTIME > 0:
    // This is an overall timer, not an intercharacter one, so we need to loop to
    // emulate an intercharacter timer.

    while((l = read(fd, buf, 33)) > 0)
        o.append(buf, l); // this overload doesn't construct a temporary std::string

    if(o.size()) { 
        // do something with o

        o = ""; // reset o
    }

    if(l == -1) // read error
        break;
}
```

Comment: I do that in the former cycle. I never break. That doesnt fix the case of a message 33 chars long.

Comment: @Jackt I just realized that changing VMIN requires a loop too and updated the answer accordingly.